# JAVAFX 8 Chart: get style of existing plotted series

Tags: css, javafx, charts, styles, javafx-8

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580561/javafx-linechart-colour-order-changes-upon-reload) which has to that day still 0 answers.

What I really want to do is having in a tableview, a column that has the symbol for the plotted data corresponding to the objects in the table view row. I have managed to generate the colours supposedly followed by the JavaFX chart. The issue I have of course is that my own colour generation works (it goes back to the first colour without fail after 8 elements), when the one from the chart has the issue outlined in my [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580561/javafx-linechart-colour-order-changes-upon-reload).

So.

**I would like now to try to pick up the style *actually* applied to each series of the chart independently from pre-supposed rule about the default order of colours. How do I do that?**

This way I could apply those to my table view and even if the colours randomly change upon reloading then at least I will know what I am looking at.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research I found that the following code allows me to get what I want, supposing I am interested in the series at index intitem:

```
plotswingschart.getData().get(intitem).getNode().getStyleClass();
```

This will produce a ObservableList  containing the following string values (here example for the series at index 8 (9th series)):

```
chart-series-line
series8
default-color2
```

From this I can then get the information that I need. that is the colour actually applied to that curve. I can then generate a symbol to be used in my tableview.

I would still be interested in an answer to the question linked, which prompted the present question...